Correct Way To Escape Quotes In PowerShell Command Run From Command Line?
I have the following command that I need to run from a batch file:
PowerShell -Command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/C "MKLINK /D "C:\Folder With Spaces\Another Folder" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Folder With Spaces""' -Verb RunAs"

however when this command is actually executed the quotes around the two folders with spaces in them is completely ignored and the command fails to run correctly.  What would be the correct approach to escape the various quotes involved in this statement?  I've tried using ` and ^ in front of the quotes surrounding the folder names but neither worked.

... in other words, this command will work fine in your batch file: MKLINK /D "C:\Folder With Spaces\Another Folder" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Folder With Spaces"

@Compo: mklink is an internal cmd.exe command, not a separate executable.

@Aacini: The OP is trying to run the mklink command with elevation, which cannot be done directly from a batch file. See also my previous comment.

Please also see this. It shows a way of configuring systems to allow the mklink command to work for non elevated users.

That's good to know, @Compo, but enabling Developer Mode also invariably enables installing apps from any source, which may not be desired. Also, elevation may situationally still be required due to lack of file-system permissions. To enable Developer Mode, run the following from an elevated cmd.exe or PowerShell session: reg.exe add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock /t REG_DWORD /f /v AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense /d 1 (takes effect instantly).



For powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, to use " characters passed to the -Command parameter as part of the PowerShell code to execute, they must be escaped, in the simplest form as \".

See this answer for details.


Due to cmd.exe's parsing quirks, " characters embedded inside a cmd /c "..." call do not require additional escaping.


Therefore:
PowerShell -Command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/C \"MKLINK /D \"C:\Folder With Spaces\Another Folder\" \"%UserProfile%\Documents\Folder With Spaces\"\"' -Verb RunAs"

